# How to transform a polygon string on a real polygon

Tags: python, polygon

I need some support to real a polygon. 
Today I have a string and I need to change in a format that is possible to recognize as a polygon.

I am acquiring directly from SQL the value of polygon:

Example:

I read on this way:

```
string = "POLYGON ((-47.158846224312285 -21.349760242365733;-47.158943117468695 -21.349706412900805;-47.159778541623055 -21.349008036758804))"
```

I need to change in this format

```
list = [(-47.158846224312285,  -21.349760242365733), (47.158943117468695 -21.349706412900805),  (-47.159778541623055, -21.349008036758804)]
```

Any idea how to modificate?

Comment: Where is the class `POLYGON` defined? Are you using a 3rd party module or is it something you have created? If it is the latter please [edit] your question and add the class definition to it.

Comment: Sorry, in this case POLYGON is no t a class, it is part of an entire string that cames from SQL

Comment: I would rewrite this question to be a little more clear. The example is clear but the introductory paragraph is confusing - specifically the statement "change in a format that is possible to recognize as a polygon."

Comment: Related: [Shapely: Polygon from String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855917/shapely-polygon-from-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try parsing the string with a regular expression via the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-re) something like this:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'''(-*\d+\.\d+ -*\d+\.\d+);*''')
s = "POLYGON ((-47.158846224312285 -21.349760242365733;-47.158943117468695 -21.349706412900805;-47.159778541623055 -21.349008036758804))"

matches = pat.findall(s)
if matches:
    lst = [tuple(map(float, m.split())) for m in matches]
    print(lst)
```

Output:

```
[(-47.158846224312285, -21.349760242365733), (-47.158943117468695, -21.349706412900805), (-47.159778541623055, -21.349008036758804)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how string your inputs are, this may be an easy case to simply use some string manipulation [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) library and some string manipulation.

```py
import re
# create a regular expression to extract polygon coordinates
polygon_re = re.compile(r"^POLYGON \(\((.*)\)\)") 
input = "POLYGON ((-47.1 -21.3;-47.1 -21.3;-47.1 -21.3))"
polygon_match = polygon_re.match(input)

if polygon_match is not None:
    coords_str = polygon_match.groups()[0]

    # parse string of coordinates into a list of float pairs
    point_strs = coord_str.split(";")
    polygon = [[float(s) for s in p.split()] for p in coords_str.split(";")]
```

Comment: martineau's regular expression handles extraction of each point string a little more cleanly.