# Shapely: Polygon from String?

Tags: python, shapely

I have saved string representations of some Shapely Polygons:

```
'POLYGON ((51.0 3.0, 51.3 3.61, 51.3 3.0, 51.0 3.0))'
```

Is there some fast way of directly converting it back to the Polygon type? Or do I need to manually parse the strings to create Polygon objects?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Shapely can directly [parse this](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#well-known-formats):

```
import shapely.wkt

P = shapely.wkt.loads('POLYGON ((51.0 3.0, 51.3 3.61, 51.3 3.0, 51.0 3.0))')
print(P)
```